# Flagging to unmark as duplicate, inappropriate use of flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I recently flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965568/webapi-file-uploading-without-writing-files-to-disk) that I believe is improperly marked as duplicate, as the two questions are asking entirely different things.

My flag was declined with the message:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Is this not a situation that requires moderator intervention? If not, why?

Comment: add comment and notify the person who closed the question and tell him why you don't agree ... by the way the question is pretty old

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, apparently that is the answer. Although the action I was suppose to take in that situation wasn't obvious and appeared that it did require moderator intervention.